# Failed to parse time string after i changed language to Arabic

Tags: php, wordpress

am not a developer i dowloaded theme for WordPress but after i change the language to arabic i had this error message

Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (٢٠٢٠/٠٢/٠٦ ١٩:٣٠) at position 0 (�): Unexpected character in C:\xampp\htdocs\Carna2\wp-content\themes\motors\inc\woocommerce_setups_rental.php:928 Stack trace: #0

here is code lines with error

```
/*$date1 = new DateTime(explode(' ', $values['pickup_date'])[0]);
    $date2 = new DateTime(explode(' ', $values['return_date'])[0]);

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");*/

    $date1 = new DateTime( $values['calc_pickup_date'] );
    $date2 = new DateTime( $values['calc_return_date'] );

    $diff = $date2->diff( $date1 )->format( "%a.%h" );

    $hm = explode('.', $diff);
```

please keep in mind i dont  have any coding experience
thnks

Comment: Could you provide the name of the theme?

Comment: Its motors theme by stylemix

Comment: But as you can  see below mohamed soultion have solved for me

Comment: Thank you khalid for your intention to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the problem is with the arabic input numbers, you need to convert them to normal digits.

If you put the code below it will resolve the error you are having:

```
//$values = ['calc_pickup_date' => '٢٠٢٠/٠٢/٠٦ ١٩:٣٠','calc_return_date' => '٢٠٢٠/٠٦/٠٦ ١٩:٣٠' ];

// function that converts arabic numbers to standard digits
$convertNumbers = function($str) {
    $westernArabic = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
    $easternArabic = array('٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩');
    return str_replace($easternArabic, $westernArabic, $str);
};

$values = array_map($convertNumbers, $values); // convert numbers

// The rest of your code but using converted inputs
$date1 = new DateTime( $values['calc_pickup_date'] );
$date2 = new DateTime( $values['calc_return_date'] );

$diff = $date2->diff( $date1 )->format( "%a.%h" );

$hm = explode('.', $diff);
```

NOTE : I guess you need someone with development skills or try to learn some basics as this issue might be just the beginning ...

Comment: Thanks for advise am a undergraduate doctor i just want to make small business site i have a general understanding of website building using readdy coded theme and plugin by wordpress